# full outer join of table on itself with missing entries

Tags: sql

I have a table as follows

```
group, identifier, date, value  
g1, a, 2015-01-31, 1  
g1, a, 2015-02-28, 2  
g2, a, 2015-02-28, 0.5  
g2, a, 2015-03-31, 1  
g1, b, 2015-01-31, 3  
g1, b, 2015-02-28, 1  
g2, b, 2015-02-28, 0  
g2, b, 2015-03-31, 2
```

I would like to create a sql query such that it gives me the values of g1 - g2, by joining on the identifier and date
for cases where g1 is not there in the table it should give be -g2, and in cases where there is no g2 it should give me g1

the result should look like this

```
identifier, date, value  
a, 2015-01-31, 1  
a, 2015-02-28, 1.5  
a, 2015-03-31, -1  
b, 2015-01-31, 3  
b, 2015-02-28, 1  
b, 2015-03-31, -2
```

Comment: I don't understand the explanation but it seems to have little to do with the results you have included.

Comment: I am asking how to do this in SQL

Comment: what SQL query have you tried?

Comment: i was trying the following query, but it does not work:  select left.identifier,  left.date, left.value - right.value as value  from table left full outer join table right  on left.identifier = right.identifier and left.date = right.date

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `JOIN`, you can do a `GROUP BY` instead. Use a `CASE` expression to sum g1 values as positive, and g2 values as negative:

```
select identifier, "date", SUM(case when "group" = 'g1' then "value"
                                    when "group" = 'g2' then -"value"
                               end) as "value"
from tablename
group by identifier, "date"
```

You may need to delimit the `date`, `group` and `value` columns since these words are reserved (at least in ANSI SQL). I.e. put those column names withing double quotes. (`"date"` etc.)